# Is this the purpose of bringing back Jon?

Tags: game-of-thrones

So was Jon Snow brought back to life in *Game of Thrones* to kill Daenerys? To me it makes sense, I'm not sure if I missed something along the way. It also backs the point that Daenerys would do no good for the world as the queen of Westeros.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to [movies.se]. We have a policy to avoid spoilers in the title. Because not many have watched the season finale yet. Title is only an introduction to your question. Body is complete question. So, please avoid spoilers in the title. You may write it in the body.

Comment: [Asked over on SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/212881/58193)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the books it is yet to be discovered if he is brought back to life for what greater purpose. But one thing is for sure, it isn't just one thing he did, but many.

Probably in the books he is the one who kills the Night King, because it was clear from David Benioff's interview that they wanted to subvert expectations, they wanted someone who was not Jon to kill the Night King. So I think in the books he came back to life for also killing the NK.

He was brought back to do a lot of things if you start to see it that way, a chain of events that led to a lot of things.

Defeated Ramsay, showed the World that the dead are coming, prepared for the Long Night and battle of Winterfell. Successfully defeating NK would not have been possible without him.

What the Lord of Light could have wanted? Well, we don't even know what LoL was, didn't know what his intentions were, who were his enemy but one thing we know for sure, all victories inevitably came at a cost. To bring a new World, Jon Snow had to stab his love in the belly. So there we have the Azor Ahai theory jumping in, not totally similar but was a good deal.

Comment: The comparisons with the books are conjecture or wrong: there is no NK in the book and Jon is still dead in the books.

Comment: Night King killing part is wrong to assume. Pure speculation. GRRM told D&D main points. NK should be one of them. BoB was won by Sansa. Excursion beyond the wall was failure due to Cersei's betrayal. Only killing Dany counts

Comment: @KharoBangdo i agree for the most part, however he stilled played a huge part in the BoB, he united the wildlings and the northmen and they fought for him.